# allowing deployment of ruby apps for different users

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, nginx with passenger.

I allowed users to deploy their own html websites in their home directories which are accessible via

> DOMAIN/~USER

using this code in nginx.conf file:

```
http{
server{
...
location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/$1/www$2;
    autoindex on;
}
...
```

how can i configure nginx with passenger that each user can deploy Ruby apps in their own directories? For example that they put them in

> DOMAIN/~USER/ruby/

Preferably without the need to modify configuration files (obviously users don't have root access) but if that's not possible then adding apps by hand by admin is also possible (not many users, not many apps).